# "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" keeps coming up :(

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program. The program calculates Latin Squares using two numbers the user enters on a previous page. But but an error keeps coming up, "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" here is the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

def template(file, **vars):
    return open(file, 'r').read() % vars

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print

form = cgi.FieldStorage() # instantiate only once!
num_1 = form.getfirst('num_1')
num_2 = form.getfirst('num_2')

int1r = str(num_1)
int2r = str(num_2)

def calc_range(int2r, int1r):
    start = range(int2r, int1r + 1)
    end = range(1, int2r)
    return start+end


int1 = int(int1r)

int2 = int(int2r)

out_str = ''

for i in range(0, int1):
    first_line_num = (int2 + i) % int1
    if first_line_num == 0:
        first_line_num = int1
    line = calc_range(first_line_num, int1)
out_str += line


print template('results.html', output=out_str, title="Latin Squares")
```

Comment: How about out_str += ''.join(line) or something like that?
Just use debugging techniques man! Which line is failing?
Insert "STOP" without quotes on any line - the interpreter will bomb then. That, if all else fails, will give you the line number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` returns a list object, so when you say

```
line = calc_range(first_line_num, int1)
```

You are assigning a list to `line`. This is why `out_str += line` throws the error.

You can use `str()` to convert a list to a string, or you can build up a string a different way to get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `out_str += line`, you're trying to add a list (from calc_range) to a string. I don't even know what this is supposed to be doing, but that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what line you're getting the error from, but I'm guessing it's:

```
out_str += line
```

The first variable is a string.  The second is a list of numbers.  You can't concatenate a list onto a string.  I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but how about:

```
out_str += ", ".join(line)
```

That will add the numbers joined by commas onto out_str.

Answer (score 0):

`calc_range()` returns a list; however, you are attempting to add it to a string (`out_str`).

It looks like your code is unfinished - don't you want to do something with the range of numbers returned by `calc_range()`? Like, say, something with the form?

```
line = ''.join(num_1[index] for index in calc_range(first_line_num, int1))
```

I don't know if that's what you want - but maybe something like that?